# How to pass row value to another angularjs controller when clicking anchor tag in row

Tags: angularjs

Here is my scenario, I have rows of data in a table with ContractId and CustomerName values from a dataset. I made the ContractId value a link when the user clicks they would be redirected to another page with the CustomerName value from that row. Now I'm struggling how to pass that value and access that value in another controller.

So I have searched the internet and learned a lot of methods how to pass values from a controller to another like services, $stateparams, $rootscopes and the $broadcast,$emit methods. I have chosen the $broadcast method since my controllers are in a hierarchy and I just need my child controller to pass the CustomerName value to the parent controller. I have tried placing a ng-click within my anchor tag and created a save event and passed my CustomerName value but I'm getting a Error: $parse:syntax Syntax Error.

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="contractCtrl">
    <div class="card" ng-controller="contractlistCtrl">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="formBank">

            <div class="card-header">
                <h2>Contract List</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body card-padding">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table ng-table="tableFilter" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle" show-filter="true">
                            <tr ng-repeat="contractDetails in $data">

                                <td data-title="'Contract No'" >
                                    <a ng-href="#/admin/contract/first" ng-click="save({{ contractDetails.CustomerName }})">{{ contractDetails.ContractId }}</a>
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Customer'" >
                                    {{ contractDetails.CustomerName }}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Sales Agent'">
                                    {{ contractDetails.SalesAgentName }}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Item Type'">
                                    {{ contractDetails.ItemTypeName}}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Item Id'" >
                                    {{ contractDetails.ItemId }}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Item Name'" >
                                    {{ contractDetails.Model }}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Payment Terms'">
                                    {{ contractDetails.TermName }}
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="'Status'" >
                                    {{ contractDetails.Status}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>            
                </div>

                <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-t-20" ng-click="generateReport(ReportId,FromDate,ToDate)">Generate</button>-->

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my child controller

```
materialAdmin
    .controller('contractlistCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, ngTableParams, $filter, contractService, $state, $timeout, $stateParams, $window) {

        contractService.getListData().then(function (result) {
            $scope.insertIntoDataTable(result);
        });

        $scope.insertIntoDataTable = function (resultData) {
            $scope.data = (resultData !== null) ? resultData : [];
            $scope.length = $scope.data.length;

            //Filtering
            $scope.tableFilter = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10
            }, {
                    total: $scope.data.length,
                    getData: function ($defer, params) {

                        var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;

                        var slice = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                        this.ContractId = slice;
                        this.CustomerName = slice;
                        this.SalesAgentName = slice;
                        this.ItemTypeName = slice;
                        this.ItemId = slice;
                        this.Model = slice;
                        this.TermName = slice;
                        this.Status = slice;

                        params.total(orderedData.length);
                        $defer.resolve(this.ContractId, this.CustomerName, this.SalesAgentName, this.ItemTypeName, this.ItemId, this.Model, this.TermName, this.Status);
                    }
                })
        }


        $scope.save = function (data) {
            $scope.$broadcast("SendDown", data);
        }

    })
```

Then I have this piece of code in my parent controller to receive the data

```
$scope.$on("SendDown", function (data) {
                $scope.customerSelected = data;
            });
```

All I'm trying to do is to pass a value to another controller when the anchor tag is clicked.

**UPDATE**

I have taken the advise of using $stateparams instead of broadcast and I got it working. I followed what was stated and added this code on another js file to set the state.

```
.state('contract.contract.contractlist', {
                url: '/first/:customer',
                templateUrl: 'views/contract_first.html',
                controller: function ($stateParams) {
                    console.log($stateParams);
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntax errors in your code. First of all here:

```
<tr ng-repeat="contractDetails in $data">
```

`$data` should be `data`.

Also, here there is no need of `{{ }}` inside `ng-click` :

```
ng-click="save(contractDetails.CustomerName)"
```

But, in general you don't need `ng-click` and you don't need `$broadcast`.
You just need to pass the value as parameter on redirection. One way to achieve that is:

```
ng-href="#/admin/contract/first/{{contractDetails.ContractId}}"
```

(It is better to send id instead of name)

And then in new state you can retrieve the value (with `$stateParams` if you are using ui-router).

**EDIT:** How to pass transition parameter without showing in url

You can use `ui-sref` directive (part of ui-router) to send the parameter to new state like this:

```
ui-sref="contract.contract.contractlist({customer: contractDetails.CustomerName})"
```

In state declaration remove the parameter from the url and add `params` field:

```
.state('contract.contract.contractlist', {
            url: '/first',
            templateUrl: 'views/contract_first.html',
            params: {
                customer: null
            }
        })
```

For documentation check here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thanks I got it working, though your advise about the wrong syntax for $data doesn't seem to affect the application since I could still display my data but I would still change it.

Comment: Followup question, since this method shows the value passed in the URL is there any way to use $stateParams without showing the value?